# Hover at the mouse

Tags: jquery, hover

How can I zoom the `<h3>` tagged text when the mouse hovers on them using jQuery?

This is the JavaScript code.

```
 var bindBehaviors = function (scope) {
            $('h3',scope).hover(
            function () {
            $(this).css("font-size", "40px");
            },
           function () {
           $(this).css("font-size", "25px");
           }
           );
           }
           bindBehaviors(this);
```

It is changing its size, but it is happening when I put the mouse anywhere on the row which contains `<h3>` text. Why?
Another problem is the positioning.

The ASPX code is the following.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
  <div id="dictionary">
  </div>
  <div class="letters">
    <div class="button" id="letter-a">
      <h3>A</h3>
      <button type="button">Load</button> 
    </div>
    <div class="button" id="letter-b">
      <h3>B</h3>
      <button type="button">Load</button> 
    </div>
    <div class="button" id="letter-c">
      <h3>C</h3>
      <button type="button">Load</button> 
    </div>
    <div class="button" id="letter-d">
      <h3>D</h3>
      <button type="button">Load</button> 
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="button" id="letter-f">F
    <form>
      <input type="text" name="term" value="" id="term" />
      <input type="submit" name="search" value="search" id="search" />
    </form>
  </div>
  <div id="loading">
    Loading...
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Just increase the font. This can be done with just css `h3:hover { font-size: 50px; }`

Comment: Try this plugin http://janne.aukia.com/zoomooz/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

html: `<h3>Some text</h3>`

css: `h3 {font-size: 14px;}`

jquery:

```
$('h3').hover(
  function () {
    $(this).css("font-size", "16px");
  },
  function () {
    $(this).css("font-size", "14px");
  }
);
```

Comment: it is working but text's font is getting change when mouse hovers on anywhere at the row where the text exist.i don't need it.it must be change size when i place/hover mouse on it.

Comment: And when i remove the mouse from it,it doesn't resize to its original size.

Comment: Sorry, had a typo. Now it should resize to the original size. As for the other issue - can you post your code?

Comment: There is another typo in the source. The selector must be String or does this work without being a String-Selector?

Comment: @rollstuhlfahrer No, you are right, that was a typo. Thanks for catching it. Is too late at night for me

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple of options.

Just css.

```
h3
{
    transform: scale(1);
}

h3:hover
{
    transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

JS(jQuery)

```
$('h3').hover(
    function()
    {
        $(this).effect('scale',{percent:200},1000);
    },
    function()
    {
        $(this).effect('scale',{percent:50},1000);
    },     
);
```

Something like could help.